# Transforming xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I realise this is a very basic question but I'm really struggling!

I want a way to transform an xml document into a html document, using an xslt stylesheet. I need to use xslt 2.0 as I want to use custom functions. I am happy to write the xsl and xml by hand in a text editor - all I want is something that puts them together and gives me a html back at the end.

I've searched online and Saxon keeps coming up, but I haven't got a clue what to do with it and the documentation doesn't make sense to me. I'd be perfectly happy to use another piece of software; whatever is easiest! I just need a bit of guidance about how to install/use something that will process the xml and xsl files for me.

Thanks

Comment: Well if installing or using a .NET application like Saxon 9 .NET or a Java application like Saxon 9 Java is really too complicated, then you might find it easier to use an online tool like http://xsltransform.net/.

Comment: Or you can use a trial version of an XML IDE like Stylus Studio, oXygen or XML Spy.

Comment: xsltransform.net doesn't support xslt 2.0. But thanks so much for the pointer about saxon9.net - I just didn't know that was what I needed to look for. Sorted now :)

Comment: xsltransfor.net uses Saxon 9.5 as an XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processor, it does support XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Oh I guess I did something wrong then. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to search for Saxon9.net

I *really* did try to find this out myself. Feel pretty stupid for asking but thanks for the help.